# micro SD-card ignores write changes and formatting

Tags: linux, sd-card

My micro SD-card behaves really strangely. It gets detected properly (using an adapter SD-card), I can copy some files to it or create new folders/files and eject it without problem. However, when I insert the card again, the new files don't show up. To make things even stranger, it also ignores getting formatted. The formatting process works without errors (I tried using `GParted`, `fdisk` and `mkdosfs`), but as soon as the card gets mounted again, it shows the same old content.

I can't pinpoint what could have caused it, as I use the card in my Android phone and no strange behaviour occurred. I first noticed this behaviour as I was copying some data to the card and couldn't find it as I inserted it back into the phone.

Is this a sign that the card went bad? Any ideas what I could try?

Comment: Does this sd card or adapter have a small switch on the side? There are write-protect switches. Let me know if that's there

Comment: There is a switch, but its in the 'not-locked' state. I also tried a USB adapter, with the same results

Comment: Have you tried changing the switch position, just for sake of testing and thoroughness?

Comment: Yes, in the locked state I can't write on the card. So that also seems to work as it should

Comment: Recover what data you can and replace the card, they have high failure rates.